# Differences between normal ARM7TDMI and ARM7TDMI used in GBA

Tags: arm

I was wondering if there are any significant differences between a plain old ARM7TDMI processor and the ARM7TDMI the GBA console uses.

I'm interested in learning to program a GBA or an ARM7 type processor, and if there are differences, it would change the compiler and equipment I need to use.

Comment: It might be useful to realize that ARM doesn't sell silicon; they license processor core designs to companies who do.

Comment: Why would there be a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if it's an ARM7TDMI, then it's an ARM7TDMI - what else?

ARM7 - [32 Bit base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#32-bit_architecture) architecture with

- T - [Thumb instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb), therefore an ARMv4T micro architecture, so no more 26 bit addressing.
- D - Debug extension (JTAG-Port)
- M - Fast multiplier
- I - enhanced ICE support

That's what ARM sold and Nintendo bought. Or more precisely, they bought an ARM7TDMI-S core, the synthesizable version, one that can be integrated with other parts into a single chip. And that's what they did :)

Good one stop shops for information to start might be

- [GBADEV.org](http://www.gbadev.org/docs.php)
- [GBATEK](http://problemkaputt.de/gbatek.htm)

For more information RC might not be the perfect forum, as it's still actual technology.

Comment: Are you sure it was ARM7TDMI-S? For the NDS at least, the CPUs are referred to as ARM946E-S and ARM7TDMI. The latter is essentially the same as what the GBA has.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are no differences whatsoever; it's a little hand-wavey but e.g. [the GBATEK document](http://problemkaputt.de/gbatek.htm) (in that link reformatted into NoCash style) appears to describe an ordinary ARM7TDMI.